# kendo.resize for dataviz object

Tags: responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, kendo-dataviz, kendo-chart

Issue with using kendo.resize inside the window.resize function. i need to bootstrap 3 functionalists for kendo chart, when i change the browser size so i used kendo.resize function. chart re sizing work perfectly only chart in visible area. as example i have kendo tab strip with two tab with 2 chart (tab 1 -chart1, tab 2-chart 2) when i click on tab 1 and re size the browser chart will re size, then go to tab 2 chart 2 is still in previous size when i re size the browser its again re size.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to look at example on kendo website:
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bootstrap/

There is exactly what you request:

here is a sample code:

```
    function resizeTabStripContent() {
        kendo.resize("#tabstrip");
    }

    $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
        animation: {
            open: { effects: "fadeIn" }
        },
        activate: resizeTabStripContent
    });

    // resize nested charts when window resizes
    $(window).resize(resizeTabStripContent);
```

It resizes charts in tab strip on window resize event and when tab is activated.

Comment: This seems to eat CPU like crazy when it runs, is there a possible change that could be made to minimize this?